# Does Appveyor support testing on Windows 10 Professional and Home?

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, appveyor

I have some users working on Windows 10 Professional and Windows 10 Home. I usually do continuous integration for windows on Appveyor, but I am not so familiar with the details of Windows versions.

I checked the Appveyor website and it says that build images "Visual Studio 2015" and "Visual Studio 2017" support Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10586, and some other Windows 10 SDKs. Now is this what I need to test with to validate Windows 10 Home and Professional? I was not sure if the SDK is the right thing to test against, or if there is some other build image I should use, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppVeyor currently provides testing on Windows Server only, however you can run builds on your own server/cloud with Bring-Your-Own-Cloud (BYOC) feature: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/byoc/